# How do I rename Warlock Minions on AzerothCore with an SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, azerothcore

I want to write an SQL query to rename my Warlock Minion(s) on [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk), but my first attempt runs into a MySQL error:

> MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

My code:

```sql
USE `acore_characters`;
SET @IMP := 416;
SET @IMP_NAME = 'NewImpName';
SET @OWNER_NAME = 'NameOfMyWarlock';
UPDATE `character_pet` SET name = @IMP_NAME WHERE `id` IN
  (SELECT p.`id` FROM `character_pet` p INNER JOIN `characters` c ON p.`owner` = c.`guid`
    WHERE c.`name` = @OWNER_NAME AND p.`entry`= @IMP);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help from [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/43610081#43610081) the following now works.

```
--------------------------
-- Variant (A): Outdated
--------------------------
USE `acore_characters`;

-- Warlock pet creatures
SET @IMP := 416;
SET @VOIDWALKER := 1860;
SET @SUCCUBUS := 1863;
SET @FELHUNTER := 417;
SET @FELGUARD := 17252;

-- Names
SET @OWNER_NAME := 'MyWarlockName';
SET @IMP_NAME :='NewImpName';
SET @VOIDWALKER_NAME := 'NewVoidwalkerNamen';
SET @SUCCUBUS_NAME := 'NewSuccubusName';
SET @FELHUNTER_NAME := 'NewFelhunterName';
SET @FELGUARD_NAME := 'NewFelguardName';

-- Update Imp Name
UPDATE `character_pet` SET name = @IMP_NAME WHERE `id` IN
  (SELECT s.`id` FROM (SELECT p.`id` FROM `character_pet` p INNER JOIN `characters` c ON p.`owner` = c.`guid`
    WHERE c.`name` = @OWNER_NAME AND p.`entry`= @IMP) s);

-- Update Voidwalker Name
UPDATE `character_pet` SET name = @VOIDWALKER_NAME WHERE `id` IN
  (SELECT s.`id` FROM (SELECT p.`id` FROM `character_pet` p INNER JOIN `characters` c ON p.`owner` = c.`guid`
    WHERE c.`name` = @OWNER_NAME AND p.`entry`= @VOIDWALKER) s);

-- Update Succubus Name
UPDATE `character_pet` SET name = @SUCCUBUS_NAME WHERE `id` IN
  (SELECT s.`id` FROM (SELECT p.`id` FROM `character_pet` p INNER JOIN `characters` c ON p.`owner` = c.`guid`
    WHERE c.`name` = @OWNER_NAME AND p.`entry`= @SUCCUBUS) s);

-- Update Felhunter Name
UPDATE `character_pet` SET name = @FELHUNTER_NAME WHERE `id` IN
  (SELECT s.`id` FROM (SELECT p.`id` FROM `character_pet` p INNER JOIN `characters` c ON p.`owner` = c.`guid`
    WHERE c.`name` = @OWNER_NAME AND p.`entry`= @FELHUNTER) s);

-- Update Felguard Name
UPDATE `character_pet` SET name = @FELGUARD_NAME WHERE `id` IN
  (SELECT s.`id` FROM (SELECT p.`id` FROM `character_pet` p INNER JOIN `characters` c ON p.`owner` = c.`guid`
    WHERE c.`name` = @OWNER_NAME AND p.`entry`= @FELGUARD) s);

-- Show result
SELECT p.`id`, p.`entry`, p.`name`, c.`name` AS `owner_name`
FROM `character_pet` p INNER JOIN `characters` c ON p.`owner` = c.`guid`
WHERE c.`name` = @OWNER_NAME;
```

I neither like the additional nested `SELECT` nor actually understand why MySQL complains without it, since the result of the inner `SELECT` is not affected by the outer `UPDATE`. The following variant uses the suggestion from  [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68392991/16453046) and performs the updates on a `JOIN`. Sadly I cannot use the "all in one update" method, since AzerothCore's minimum requirement for MySQL is 5.7 and the `WITH ... VALUES` construct apparently requires 8.x.

```
--------------------------
-- Variant (B): Current
--------------------------
USE `acore_characters`;

-- Names (parameters)
SET @OWNERNAME := 'MyWarlockName';
SET @IMPNAME :='NewImpName';
SET @VOIDWALKERNAME := 'NewVoidwalkerNamen';
SET @SUCCUBUSNAME := 'NewSuccubusName';
SET @FELHUNTERNAME := 'NewFelhunterName';
SET @FELGUARDNAME := 'NewFelguardName';

-- Warlock pet creatures (constants)
SET @IMP := 416;
SET @VOIDWALKER := 1860;
SET @SUCCUBUS := 1863;
SET @FELHUNTER := 417;
SET @FELGUARD := 17252;

-- Update Imp Name
UPDATE `character_pet` p INNER JOIN `characters` c ON p.`owner` = c.`guid`
SET p.`name` = @IMPNAME
WHERE p.`entry` = @IMP AND c.`name` = @OWNERNAME;

-- Update Voidwalker Name
UPDATE `character_pet` p INNER JOIN `characters` c ON p.`owner` = c.`guid`
SET p.`name` = @VOIDWALKERNAME
WHERE p.`entry` = @VOIDWALKER AND c.`name` = @OWNERNAME;

-- Update Succubus Name
UPDATE `character_pet` p INNER JOIN `characters` c ON p.`owner` = c.`guid`
SET p.`name` = @SUCCUBUSNAME
WHERE p.`entry` = @SUCCUBUS AND c.`name` = @OWNERNAME;

-- Update Felhunter Name
UPDATE `character_pet` p INNER JOIN `characters` c ON p.`owner` = c.`guid`
SET p.`name` = @FELHUNTERNAME
WHERE p.`entry` = @FELHUNTER AND c.`name` = @OWNERNAME;

-- Update Felguard Name
UPDATE `character_pet` p INNER JOIN `characters` c ON p.`owner` = c.`guid`
SET p.`name` = @FELGUARDAME
WHERE p.`entry` = @FELGUARD AND c.`name` = @OWNERNAME;

-- Show result
SELECT p.`id`, p.`entry`, p.`name`, c.`name` AS `owner_name`
FROM `character_pet` p INNER JOIN `characters` c ON p.`owner` = c.`guid`
WHERE c.`name` = @OWNERNAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the subquery at all, just use a JOIN

```
UPDATE character_pet p
INNER JOIN characters c 
    ON p.owner = c.guid 
    AND c.name = @OWNER_NAME 
    AND p.entry = @IMP
SET name = @IMP_NAME
```

If you are doing multiple updates, you can also join to a `VALUES` statement

```
WITH vals(id, newname) AS (
    VALUES (416, 'NewImpName'),
           (1860, 'NewVoidwalkerName')
           (1863, 'NewSuccubusName')
           (417, 'NewFelhunterName')
           (17252, 'NewFelguardName'))
UPDATE character_pet p
INNER JOIN vals v
    ON p.entry = v.id
INNER JOIN characters c 
    ON p.owner = c.guid
    AND c.name = 'MyWarlockName'
SET p.name = v.newname
```

Comment: That's pretty neat, but `WITH` and `VALUES` require `MySQL 8.X`, if I'm not mistaken, and the current minimum requiremnent for AzerothCore is `MySQL >= 5.7`.